# Proving a bound.

Tags: inequality

I want to prove the following bound

> For any $\theta\in [0,\pi/2]$ we have that 
>   $$\displaystyle\frac{\theta}{\sin \theta}\leq \pi$$

I wanted to use derivatives of the function $f(\theta)=\displaystyle\frac{\theta}{\sin \theta}$ and making it equals zero to find the maximum but I found the condition 
$$\tan \theta =\theta$$
I believe that there is no value between $[0,\pi/2]$ which can make the equation holds but I don't know how to prove it.

Does Somebody has a hint?

Comment: Why not study function $f:\theta \mapsto \sin\theta - \frac{\theta}{\pi}$ ?

Comment: Actually, you may prefer $f:\theta\mapsto \sin\theta-\frac{2\theta}{\pi}$, which gives a better bound...

Comment: I don't know what should I do with that function. Can you explain me?

Comment: Just study its variations. You'll find that it's positive on $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$, and you'll deduce $\sin\theta\ge\frac{2\theta}{\pi}$, which is equivalent to $\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}\le \frac\pi2$.

Comment: Well the derivative of $\tan{\theta}$ is $\sec^2{\theta}$, which is always greater than or equal to one, with equivalence only in the case $\theta=0$. Thus for $[0,\pi/2]$, $\tan{\theta}\>\theta$

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? It was useful!